# Изменение ссылки в mod_rewrite на ЧПУ

Tags: mod_rewrite, чпу

Как поменять

```
http://mysite.com/category/page-name?post_type=question
```

на это:

```
http://mysite.com/staticcategory/page_name
```

Comment: куда добавить? =)

Comment: в mod_rewrite

Comment: ну так бы и написали сразу)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category(.*)$              http://mysite.com/static/category$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: не проверял